# Python, Django: Editing inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

inside my app I'm using an inlineformset_factory and right know it's working fine! But when displaying it inside my template the labels are always staying right above the input-field. Is there any way to display them side-by-side or even move the label as some sort of placeholder inside the input-field?

**views.py**

```
formset = inlineformset_factory(Model_A, Model_B, can_delete=False, extra=0, fields=('fields_01', 'fields_02', 'fields_03'))
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Thanks for all your help and have a great weekend!

Comment: show us your templates

Comment: You need to post the html render and CSS for this because this is a markup issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.management_form }}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {{field.product.label}} - {{field.product}}   #here product is my field name
                            <hr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
 </form>
```

You have to do this for every field

#Changes

```
 <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form.Field_name.label }}  -  {{form.Field_name}} #1st field

            {{ form.Field_name.label }}  -  {{form.Field_name}} #2nd field
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the displaying was influenced by css。
Use F12 to check css in chrome to find the reason。
You can edit the css to change the displaying.
Or use django-widgets-improved and bootstrap to set class to the fields of form.

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
 <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% for field in form %}
              {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```